# How to use multiple diskStorage destinations in same controller with nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, nestjs

I have an uploads controller that has two routes setup. One for `files` and one for `photos`. They're essentially the same, but I have different `diskStorage` destinations. The problem is it seems whichever one is last in the controller is the `diskStorage` that gets set for both routes. It may be just my misunderstanding how things work, but it seems like I should be able to do this. The way it's setup now, the `files` get saved in the `photos` folder because `photos` route is last, but if I swap the order of the routes, then they get saved in the `files` folder as expected. Here is the code snippet.

```
  @Post('files')
  @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files', null, {
    storage: diskStorage({
      destination: `${__dirname}../../../uploads/files`,
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          const randomName = 'a random name';
          cb(null, `${randomName}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
        },
    }),
  }))
 async upload(@UploadedFiles() files) {
    return files;
  }

  @Post('photos')
  @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files', null, {
    storage: diskStorage({
      destination: `${__dirname}../../../uploads/photos`,
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          const randomName = 'a random name';
          cb(null, `${randomName}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
        },
    }),
  }))
  async uploadPhotos(@UploadedFiles() photos) {
    return photos;
  }
```

Comment: Version v5.2.0 was just released. :-)

Comment: Confirmed. Updating to v5.2.0 fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

> Fixed in v5.2.0. Will publish soon

Should be resolved with an update to v5.2.0 which was just released.

## Original Answer

I think this is a bug with the `FilesInterceptor`. I have openend a [Github issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/935) for it.

As a workaround you can either use the `FileInterceptor` (for single files) or define the two endpoints `files` and `photos` in two different `@Controller`s. Both ways worked when I tested it locally.